# Using IIF function in OPENQUERY

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql, linked-server, iif, openquery

```
Declare @OPENQUERY nvarchar(500), @TSQL nvarchar(max), @LinkedServer nvarchar(20), @PickedDate varchar(8)

Set @LinkedServer = 'LinkedServerName'
Set @OPENQUERY = 'Select * From Openquery('+ @LinkedServer + ','''
Set @TSQL = 'SELECT sum(iif(left(code,1)=''''C'''', 1, 0) As ActiveCases
            From cases
            Where cases.date_opened = ''''' + @vcPickedDate + '''''
            '')'
Exec (@Openquery+@TSQL)
```

When I ran this query, it returned message

> "[Sybase][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Syntax error near '=' on line 1".
>   An error occurred while preparing the query "SELECT
>   Sum(IIf(Left(code,1)='C',1,0)) AS Cases FROM cases WHERE
>   cases.date_opened = '20150511' " for execution against OLE DB provider
>   "MSDASQL" for linked server "LinkedServerName".

I figured this has something to do with openquery. It works fine if I simply run the following query without using openquery:

```
SELECT sum(iif(left(code,1)=''''C'''', 1, 0) As ActiveCases
                From cases
                Where cases.date_opened = ''''' + @vcPickedDate + '''''
```

Comment: I think the issue is with your use of escaped single-quotes.

Comment: Have you tried using the native client OLEDB provider  - MSDASQL is old (SQLNCLI12) ?

Comment: I have to use MSDASQL, OLEDB Provider for ODBC drivers. But your comment helps me solve the problem. Thanks Erik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the version of SQL Server you are using is under 2012 and `IIF` is not supported for earlier versions.

You can use `CASE` instead.

```
SELECT Sum(CASE Left(matcode,1) WHEN 'R' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Cases
FROM cases
WHERE cases.date_opened = '20150511'
```

**Edit**

Based on Zerubbabel comment, he is using `SQL Server 2014` and the problem was for using `MSDASQL` which is quite old and it doesn't support `IIF` function. So the problem has nothing to do about `IIF` in SQL Server but in `OPENQUERY`.

```
SELECT Sum(CASE Left(code,1) WHEN ''''C'''' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Cases
FROM cases
WHERE cases.date_opened = '20150511'
```

Comment: It's not the SQL server I am using that is old, I use 2014. It's probably the linked server provider MSDASQL, which is old. So sqluser's answer is close and  ErikEJ's comment is helpful too. And I do have to use CASE instead of IIF. The following query works. I'll accept sqluser's answer if you update yours. Note this question is not simply about problem with using IIF in SQL server, but using it in an Openquery!

    SELECT Sum(CASE Left(code,1) WHEN ''''C'''' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Cases
    FROM cases
    WHERE cases.date_opened = '20150511'

Comment: It's good you found the proper answer for your question. I edited my answer. Hopefully it can be useful for someone else. Feel free to edit it. Doesn't matter if you choose this one or yours as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this query will help you :

```
Set @TSQL = 'SELECT sum(iif(left(code,1)=''''C'''', 1, 0) As ActiveCases From cases
        Where cases.date_opened = '+''''''+@PickedDate+''''''+''')';
```

Comment: Not at all. Where cases.date_opened = ''''' + @vcPickedDate + ''''' works perfectly fine.Just so you know, your query print out just the same as mine.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the SQL server I am using that is old, I use 2014. It's the linked server provider MSDASQL, which is old. So sqluser's answer is close and  ErikEJ's comment is helpful too. And I do have to use CASE instead of IIF. The query below works. NOTE that this question is not simply about issue using IIF in SQL server, but using it in an `openquery`.

```
SELECT Sum(CASE Left(code,1) WHEN ''''C'''' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Cases
FROM cases
WHERE cases.date_opened = '20150511'
```